# C#, add row to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have Form with DataGridView and Button. DataGridView shows data from ArrayList, and I want to add elements to ArrayList by DataGridView. So, I’m trying this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Student.students;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student st = new Student();
            Student.students.Add(st);
        }
    }
```

But this doesn’t work… How can I add new row to this DataGridView?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List does not implement IBindingList so the grid does not know about your new items.

Bind your DataGridView to a BindingList instead.

here is the example

Your class ,

```
class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In code behind,

```
   BindingList<Student> STUDENTS;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            STUDENTS = new BindingList<Student>();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = STUDENTS;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            STUDENTS.Add(new Student { ID =1 , Name ="test" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = STUDENTS;
        }
```